# Setting cookie for site in http and https under different subdomains in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, https

Situation:

1. I'm trying run an https store (xcart) under one domain *secure.example.com* and I want to have access to a cookie it sets in http *www.example.com*
2. I'm running PHP on Apache (MAMP), testing in Firefox with Firecookie
3. The existing code sets cookies to `.secure.example.com`. I'm not sure if this is xcart related, but `setcookie` is actually called using `secure.example.com`. I'm not sure why the "`.`" is appended.

Problems:

1. When I try to use `setcookie` in https to use the domain `.example.com` or just `example.com`, no cookie is created, whether I'm running the store under http or https. The testing code I'm using is:

   ```
   setcookie('three', 'two', 0, "/", ".example.com");
   ```

If I set the cookie to `secure.example.com` or `.secure.example.com` it does show up.

Is there a reason the cookie isn't showing up?

Comment: Gumbo - Looks like nilacqua is using .example while calling setcookie as he was using localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I was using localhost with a one word domain, 'mydomain', a fact which for some reason was edited out of the original message. At least firefox requires at least two words for an explicitly set cookie, something like mydomain.local. I changed the hosts file to have the domains: www.mydomain.local and secure.mydomain.local, and I was able to set the cookies to .mydomain.local.

Also I found that php automatically puts a "." in front of explicitly set cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but the policy is determined by the browser (and on some browsers can be configured).

IIRC the semantics of the preceding . are explained in the cooke RFCs (2109 for the standard cookies states:

> A is a FQDN string and has the form NB, where N is a non-empty name
>   string, B has the form .B', and B' is a FQDN string.  (So, x.y.com
>   domain-matches .y.com but not y.com.)

Which I would interpret as meaning that a domian in a setcookie directive intended to be used as a wildcard match should be preceded by a '.' i.e. .example.com - however the spec goes on to say:

> Domain=domain
>        Optional.  The Domain attribute specifies the domain for which the
>        cookie is valid.  An explicitly specified domain must always start
>        with a dot.

Which to me implies the opposite.

I suggest you [read it](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) yourself and experiment.

The obvious practical solution is, in the absence of a suitable cookie, to redirect back to the cookie-setting webserver for it to check its cookie then send back another redirect to the originating server with cookie details in the query string, then drop a copy of the cookie associated with the current server.

Alternatively you may get some mileage out of using FQDNs with more sections, e.g.

secure.www.example.com

and

www.example.com

(dropping the cookie for [.]www.example.com)

HTH

C.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `setcookie('three', 'two', 0, "/", ".mydomain.com");` ?

Comment: I'm running this on localhost right now, so I don't have .com at the end, just www.mydomain and secure.mydomain

Comment: Add a host file entry(C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) to any domain and map it to your local machine's IP.

Ensure that domain is not going through any proxies in your browser.